# jQuery trigger when 2/3s of div are in viewport

Tags: jquery, scroll, viewport

I need to change "active" menu item on one-page website, when user slide down or up and something like two thirds of div are visible in viewport. I found some jQuery plugins, but all of them was when whole div is viewed.

Simply I need to act same like on this page: `https://vivaldi.com/`

And my page will look something like: http://jsfiddle.net/kwbddvau/2/

```css
html{height:calc(100% - 100px) !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

body{height:500% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

.page {height:20% !important; width:100% !important;}

#page1{background-color:red; margin-top: 100px;}

#page3{background-color:green;}

#page5{background-color:blue;}

#menu{width: 100%; height: 100px; color: #fff; background-color: black; position: fixed; top:0px}

#menu a {color: white; text-decoration:none;}

#menu a.active {color: red; text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><div id="menu"><a href="#page1" class="active">Home</a> | <a href="#page2">Page 2</a> | <a href="#page3">Page 3</a> | <a href="#page4">Page 4</a> | <a href="#page5">Page 5</a></div>
</div>
<div id="page1" class="page">
page1
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">
page2
</div>
<div id="page3" class="page">
page3
</div>
<div id="page4" class="page">
page4
</div>
<div id="page5" class="page">
page5
</div>
```

Comment: _"I need to change "active" menu"_ . "active" not appear at OP ? Can describe expected result of "change" ? What is requirement ?

Comment: Expected result is when I scroll for example to div#page2, then menu item page2 get `li .active {text-decoration: underline;}` exactly like it is on vivaldi.com

Comment: You really don't understand me, I don't mean two thirds of whole page but two thirds of each div. #page1, #page2,...,#page5 are sub-pages on one-page layout. I will edit code snippet id question and maybe it will be more clear. But I want it to act like on vivaldi.com, when you scroll on that page down and up, "active class" on menu items is changing and give them red border-bottom or something like that.

Comment: Rather than looking to see if the divs are visible can't you just determine the heights of the divs and then determine between what heights you want the different menus then when a scroll happens, see what height you are at and set the menu depending on that?

Comment: edited, now in div#menu are items, on page load is visible only div#page1 so by default first link in menu has .active, now what I need is when I scroll down and on my viewport is visible #page2 more than any other page div (lets say I have on viewport one third of #page1 and two thirds of #page2) to remove .active class from first link in menu and give it to second link and so on. And opposite when I scroll up and on viewport I see more of #page1 than #page2 I need to change .active back to first link. Exactly same as on vivaldi.com

Comment: @Neilos I think I can't, because div height is always different based on viewport height of user browser window.

Comment: Of course you can... just get the height using jQuery. it doesn't matter if it is dynamic. However you will need to recompute everything each time the viewport dimensions change.

Comment: @AdamVýborný See post.

Comment: @Neilos This sounds interesting, but looks much more complicated and I have no idea how it should be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var page = $(".page")
, menu = $("#menu");
$(window).on("scroll", function (e) {    
    var res = $.grep(page, function (el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 180 && (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 180)
   });
    var id = res.slice(-1)[0].id;  
    menu.find("." + id)
    .addClass("active")
    .siblings()
    .removeClass("active")   
}).scroll();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kwbddvau/8/

---

```js
var page = $(".page")
, menu = $("#menu");
$(window).on("scroll", function (e) {    
var res = $.grep(page, function (el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 180 && (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 180)
   });
var id = res.slice(-1)[0].id;  
menu.find("." + id)
.addClass("active")
.siblings()
.removeClass("active")   
}).scroll();
```

```css
html {
    height:calc(100% - 100px) !important;
    width:100% !important;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    height:500% !important;
    width:100% !important;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.page {
    height:20% !important;
    width:100% !important;
}
#page1 {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#page3 {
    background-color:green;
}
#page5 {
    background-color:blue;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px
}
.active {
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="menu"> <span class="page1">MENU</span>  <span class="page2">MENU</span>  <span class="page3">MENU</span>
 <span class="page4">MENU</span>  <span class="page5">MENU</span>

</div>
<div id="page1" class="page">page1</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">page2</div>
<div id="page3" class="page">page3</div>
<div id="page4" class="page">page4</div>
<div id="page5" class="page">page5</div>
```

Comment: Something like that, but this work only when whole div is visible on viewport else it gives class active to fourth menu item, no matter where you are

Comment: Now it works great, still its not changing in two of thrids div, but in top of div. But I satisfied with that. Many thanks!

Comment: See updated post. Initially interpreted "2/3" as "2/3" of all `div` , or `3.3` . You are welcome:)

Comment: No its better, but still not 2/3, but something like 8/10.