# Check which div fixed nav is current over with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a fixed nav on a single-page site with links that when clicked scroll to specific section ID's like this:

```
<nav>
    <a class="current" href="#intro"></a>
    <a href="#about"></a>
    <a href="#contact"></a>
</nav>
```

When a user scrolls down I want to mark which nav item is current based on which section the fixed nav is currently over. For instance, if the `<nav>` is currently over `<section id="about">`, I want `<a href="#about"></a>` to have a class of "current". If then the user scrolls down to `<section id="contact">`, `<a href="#contact"></a>` should have a class of "current".

Comment: please post what you have tried so far and explain what problems you are having with your attempt

Comment: What about the case when the bottom edge of a section and the top edge of the following section are both in the view port? which link should be highlighted, the link to the top visible section or the following section?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a click handler to all links in the nav.  Add "current" to the clicked link, and remove "current" from all of the links siblings (the other `<a>` elements in the nav).

```
$("nav a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current")
})
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140800/jquery-trigger-when-2-3s-of-div-are-in-viewport