# how to execute code when arriving to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at some similar questions, but couldn't find a solution that worked for me. I have some counters on my page, and I want them to start counting only when I reach that div in my view. any ideas? Thanks.

Here's my code...:

```js
// JS plugin + code for counter up


(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
            
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };

})(jQuery);
      
jQuery(function($) {
    
        var div_header = $('#counters').offset().top;
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        //alert(window_top);
        //alert(div_header);
        
        if(div_header == window_top) {
            alert('success');
        }
    
        $('.hours span').countTo({
            from: 50,
            to: 1400,
            speed: 2000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
        $('.exposure span.numbers').countTo({
                from: 50,
                to: 300,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                    console.debug(this);
                }
            });
        $('.types span').countTo({
                from: 0,
                to: 10,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                    console.debug(this);
                }
            });
    });
```

```css
#counters {
 font-family: 'opensans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    background-color: #222020;
}

#counters div {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#counters span, .exposure:after {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="counters">
    <div class="hours">
        <span></span>
        <h3>header1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="exposure">
        <span class="numbers"></span><span>%</span>
        <h3>header2</h3>    
    </div>
    <div class="types">
        <span></span>
        <h3>header3</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"I want them to start counting only when I reach that div in my view"_ What do you mean by "reach that div"?

Comment: when the div reaches the window view. something like this:
'var div_header = $('#counters').offset().top;
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        //alert(window_top);
        //alert(div_header);
        
        if(div_header == window_top) {
            alert('success');
        }'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140800/jquery-trigger-when-2-3s-of-div-are-in-viewport/29142018#29142018

Comment: Thank you, it works. @guest271314