# Trigger event when certain scroll distance is reached jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vh based website with elements I want to show when a certain vh has been scrolled. I tried using an if statement with a variable for distance scrolled, but it doesn't update constantly so it doesn't work:

```
var distancePX = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var distanceVH = scroll/height * 100;
if (distance >= 170) {
    //ACTIONS
};
```

What can I use to make a constantly updating version of above?

Comment: You can see some examples here: [javascript: detect scroll end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end/24808540#24808540), or [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event/24815216#24815216)

Comment: See [jQuery trigger when 2/3s of div are in viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140800/jquery-trigger-when-2-3s-of-div-are-in-viewport/29142018#29142018)

Answer (score 2):

Using pure JS, you could use the `onscroll` event and bind it to the body. Here's an example:

HTML

```
<body onscroll="myFunction()">
  ...
</body>
```

JS

```
var distancePX = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var distanceVH = scroll/height * 100;

function myFunction() {
  if (distance >= 170) {
    //ACTIONS
  }
}
```

You can also use jQuery's `scroll()` method if you prefer a non-markup solution. With this method, you just place your if statement inside a `scroll()` function. Here's an example:

```
var distancePX = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var distanceVH = scroll/height * 100;

$("body").scroll(function(){
  if (distance >= 170) {
    //ACTIONS
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 170) {
                //actions...
            } else {
                //actions...
            }
        });
```