# Change color when user has scrolled down enough and then back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs arranged vertically one on top of the other which from here on out I will call **panels**. Each panel has the width and height of the viewport. All panels have the same background color at all times. Initially, that color is black.

Every other panel is empty, and acts as a gap between panels that actually have content. The order is like this:

1. Content
2. No content
3. Content
4. No content
5. Content

What I want to do is make it so that when a user has scrolled down enough for a panel **with** content to be out of view, the color should change from black to white. Then, once they have scrolled far enough for the second panel with content to be out of view, it should change back.

This is the part I cannot figure out. I have a working demo with my code so far:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {

  var viewportHeight = $("html").outerHeight();
  var currentY = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (currentY % viewportHeight != 0) {
    lighten();
  } else {
    darken();
  }
});

function darken() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "black");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "black");
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, my code is a ways off from achieving the desired result. Not only is the order wrong, the main problem is that it only triggers when the user is at the exact Y for the change to happen.

The order should be:

1. Black
2. White
3. White
4. Black
5. Black
6. White
7. White
8. Black
9. Black

etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` `.top` and `.botton` properties?

Comment: See [jQuery trigger when 2/3s of div are in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140800/jquery-trigger-when-2-3s-of-div-are-in-viewport/)

Comment: @thsise.. sorry i don't know jquery.. so i changed some part of your code

Comment: I think, I didnt understand your question well.. please clear.. 1) The order should be black,white,white,black,black...with repect to what..content or panel?  2)  whats wrong with my answer.

Comment: 3) 'What I want to do is make it so that when a user has scrolled down enough for a panel with content to be out of view, the color should change from black to white. Then, once they have scrolled far enough for the second panel with content to be out of view, it should change back.` .. please be specific what percentage are you talking about.. 'out of view'   'far enough' doesn't make sense.. where should be the user when both transition should take place

Comment: just edited my answer..given an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I'm pretty sure this is the order you need.

```
(function() {
    var lastfunc = darken;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(document).scrollTop();
        var x = $("html").outerHeight();
        var func = (Math.floor(((y + x) / (2 * x))) % 2) ? lighten : darken;
        if (func !== lastfunc) {
            lastfunc = func;
            func();
        }
    });
})();
```

This does the following:

1. Create a variable `lastfunc` to keep track of the last thing we called.
2. Get the user's Y and the height of the viewport.
3. Use evil factorized math to get a bool which decides which of the two functions, `lighten()` or `darken()` to assign to `func`.
4. Check to see if `lastfunc` is equal to `func`, to see if a change is necessary.

   - If they are not equal, call `func()` and set `lastfunc` equal to `func`

This has the following benefits:

1. All wrapped up to prevent making `lastfunc` a global.
2. Math is solid.
3. This calls the style modifying functions **only if** a change is required.

I've also optimized your `darken()` and `lighten()` functions:

```
function darken() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}
```

This slight optimization saves jQuery the trouble of finding your `body`, which should save off a couple of milliseconds. Not a huge difference, but this is optimal.

Additional note: if you are able to get rid of the second style change in `lighten` and `darken`, we can get rid of the overhead of having the function calls at all, and do it all within `scroll()`:

```
(function() { 
    var lastColor;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(document).scrollTop();
        var color = (Math.floor(((y + x) / (2 * x))) % 2) ? "red" : "blue";
        if (color !== lastColor) {
            lastColor = color;
            document.body.style.color = color;
        }
    });
})();
```

Demo of the first solution:

```js
(function() {
    var lastfunc = darken;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(document).scrollTop();
        var x = $("html").outerHeight();
        var func = (Math.floor(((y + x) / (2 * x))) % 2) ? lighten : darken;
        if (func !== lastfunc) {
            lastfunc = func;
            func();
        }
    });
})();

function darken() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The order looks good, Ill check it thoroughly and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {

  var viewportHeight = $("html").outerHeight();
  var currentY = $(document).scrollTop();
  var panelNumber = Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight);
  if (panelNumber % 4 === 1 || panelNumber % 4 === 2) {
    lighten();
  } else {
    darken();
  }
});

function darken() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "black");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "black");
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
</body>
```

> Not only is the order wrong, the main problem is that it only triggers
>   when the user is at the exact Y for the change to happen.

yes..that is right. `currentY % viewportHeight != 0` will not work. Scrolling is not smooth. Pulling scrollbar down may result in change of 10000 px/sec, but browser renders 60fps which means your `currentY` (scroll-y)  will increase by 150px every frame (your are expecting a change of 1px). So if your code contains `if(currentY === 100){}`  definitely not going to work. `currentY` may have values like  `0,50,80,99,120,...`.

It should be clear `currentY % viewportHeight != x` is not so much different.

So `if(0<currentY<500)` will be be better option.

Now suppose `viewportHeight = 500`. We can get `panelNumber =  Math.floor(currentY/viewportHeight)` (=>0,1,2,3,4,5...)

(Not clear from your question) Suppose you want to have 
panel: 0 =>black, 1=>white, 2=>white, 3=>black, 4=>black ...
you can get black by `panelNumber%4==0 || panelNumber%4==3`.

[please change accordingly if you want something different]

Comment: Why this answer was down voted while it gives the correct result?

Comment: People often downvote answers that are just code witgout explanation. Especially when there's this much code. Although I don't know why they'd waste their reputation on it unless the answer is really bad.

Comment: The order seems correct but its a bit confusing bc you have not removed the "Content" from panels that are supposed to be blank. Ill check it thoroughly and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but I made a solution for this and didn't had time to post it.

So: "How is my solution any different?"

I get gap-from-top values to all your **.blank** divs and then check where view-port is located. This allows you to use borders, add any other divs  in between, change size of your divs and this will not lose functionality.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("blank");
var i;
var marks = [];
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  var rect = elem[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  marks.push(rect.top);
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if (findi() % 2 == 1) {
    lighten();
  } else {
    darken();
  }
});

function findi() {
  pos = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    if (marks[i] < $(document).scrollTop()) {
      pos++;
    }
  }
  return (pos);
}

function darken() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "black");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "black");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel {
  border-bottom: 32px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel blank">
</div>
<div class="panel content">
  <h2> CONTENT </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.hover()` on `$(document).ready();` I have added an example of it if it works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".panel.content").hover(function(){
       $("body").css("background-color", "white");
       $(this).css("color", "black");
  },function(){
       $("body").css("background-color", "black");
       $(this).css("color", "white");
  });
  
});

$(document).scroll(function() {

  $(".panel.content").hover(function(){
       $("body").css("background-color", "white");
       $(this).css("color", "black");
  },function(){
       $("body").css("background-color", "black");
       $(this).css("color", "white");
  });
  
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, however it shouldn't have to rely on the user's pointer being on top of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition in your code

`Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight) % 4 == 1 || Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight) % 4 == 2`

and your code is working now.

**Testing**

If you run this code in java it will display same output as you expected.

```
public static void main(String...arr){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        if(i%4 ==1 || i%4 == 2){
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {

      var viewportHeight = $("html").outerHeight();
      var currentY = $(document).scrollTop();
      
      if (Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight) % 4 == 1 || Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight) % 4 == 2) {
        lighten();
      } else {
        darken();
      }
    });
    
    function darken() {
      $("body").css("background-color", "black");
      $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
    }

    function lighten() {
      $("body").css("background-color", "white");
      $(".panel.content").css("color", "black");
    }
```

```css
  html,
    body,
    .panel {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-color: black;
      overflow-y: visible;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: background-color 500ms linear;
    }

    .panel {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .content {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div class="panel content">
        <h2> CONTENT </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel blank">
      </div>
      <div class="panel content">
        <h2> CONTENT </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel blank">
      </div>
      <div class="panel content">
        <h2> CONTENT </h2>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Order is incorrect. The color should change on the panel *before* the last content panel.

Comment: An explanation as to what the problem with the OP's method was, why this answer solves the problem, and how, would be greatly helpful to us, newbies. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've made it so you can choose which panel sets the background color to white/black. You can do that by adding the class 'black' or 'white' to it, though the way you requested it makes perfect sense afterall.
Also my solution uses a class to change the background color of the body. This should make it more easy to make style changes.

```js
$(document).ready(init)

function init(){
 $(document).scroll(updateBackground)
 updateBackground()
}

function updateBackground(){
 var w = $(window).width()
 var h = $(window).height()
 var panels = $('.panel') // get all panels on page

 for(var i=0;i<panels.length;i++){ // loop though each panel
  var panel = panels.eq(i) // get the current panel
  var panel_y = panel.offset().top - $(document).scrollTop() // get the panels y coordinate relative to the window
  var panel_height = panel.height() // get the panels height
  if(panel_y<=0 && panel_y+panel_height>0){ // check if the panel is in the visible area
   if(panel.hasClass('black')){ // check if the panel is set to make the background black
    $('body').removeClass('white')
    $('body').addClass('black')
   }else if(panel.hasClass('white')){
    $('body').removeClass('black')
    $('body').addClass('white')
   }
   return // return, because we already found the visible panel
  }
 }
}
```

```css
html{
  height: 100%
}
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 transition: background-color 500ms linear;
  height: 100%
}
body.white{
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}
body.black{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
.panel{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 50px;
 border: solid 1px #888888;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.panel > h1{
 font-size: 38pt;
} 
.panel > p{
 font-size: 18pt;
 line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head
<body>

<div class="panel with-content black">
 <h1>Content</h1>
 <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="panel gap white"></div>

<div class="panel with-content white">
 <h1>Content</h1>
 <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="panel gap black"></div>

<div class="panel with-content black">
 <h1>Content</h1>
 <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="panel gap white"></div>

<div class="panel with-content white">
 <h1>Content</h1>
 <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 </p>
</div>

<div class="panel gap black"></div>

<div class="panel with-content black">
 <h1>Content</h1>
 <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is make it so that when a user has scrolled down enough for a panel with content to be out of view, the color should change from black to white. Then, once they have scrolled far enough for the second panel with content to be out of view, it should change back.

This statement conflicts with the order you mentioned. From the statement, it is implied that the color changes should be alternate, but the order mentioned in your question is not alternate.

Please see the below code which changes colors on alternate `div`s through out the scrolling.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {

  var viewportHeight = $("html").outerHeight();
  var currentY = $(document).scrollTop();
  
  if (Math.floor(currentY / viewportHeight) % 2) {
    lighten();
  } else {
    darken();
  }
});

function darken() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "black");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "white");
}

function lighten() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  $(".panel.content").css("color", "black");
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel blank">
  </div>
  <div class="panel content">
    <h2> CONTENT </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The order is incorrect. Read the specification closer. The color shouldn't change on content divs, only on blank ones.